# CakePHP 3 refresh page after form submit

Tags: forms, cakephp, submit

I have created a website using cakePHP 3.I have created a mail form in the contact section using the form helper and the mail sender. The mail is working OK, but when I click the send (submit) button, it reloads the contact page and keep de input fields filled.

What I want is to not refresh the page, clear the form fields and show a modal. ¿Is this possible? ¿How can I do it?

I don't know if you guys need any code, so if you need it I will provide it.

Thanks.

Comment: `I want is to not refresh the page` - that means you submit the form with js. You should _always_ put code in a question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want clear fields after submit form you can do in two way:

in view:

```
<?= $this->Form->input('email',['value' => '']); ?>
```

or in controller method after calling execute method unset your submited data like this:

```
$contact = new ContactForm();
if ($contact->execute($this->request->data)) {
   $this->request->data = [];

}
```

If sending success , you can set success flash message or other variable, and then in view display flash message or modal

```
$this->Flash->success(__('The Message has been sent.'));
// or
$this->set('modal', true);
```

in your view

```
<?php if(isset($modal) && $modal == true): ?>
   YOUR MODAL HERE
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but none of clearing fields solutions works. With the first one, the page still refreshing with the inputs filled. With the second one, I gen a submit error.

Comment: You want to remove form from page after post?

Comment: No, I want to clear the input fields after send the email. Thanks

Comment: @IanOrtega I update secound solution. Now both works. http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cDh0DZieS6